# failed to connect to using retrofit and php script

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using retrofit to get data from mysql/php
and everything work fine until 3 to 4 minutes an error show up saying

failed to connect to besthuge.com/192.185.48.171 (port 80) after 10000ms

just to mention i keeping connecting to site and try to get data in real time

the code below is my retrofit code

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(api.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    api ap = retrofit.create(api.class);

    Call<List<db>> call = ap.getData();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<db>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<db>> call, Response<List<db>> response) {
            List<db> dbs = response.body();

                Log.d("array",""+dbs.get(dbs.size()-1).getTemp());


                temper.add(String.valueOf(dbs.get(dbs.size()-1).getTemp()));
                Log.d("size", temper.size()+"");
                Log.d(" data", temper.get(temper.size()-1)+"");

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<db>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```